# Qwt append point to plot

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4, qwt

I'm writing my first program using Qwt.  I've created a QwtCurve object and I used QwtCurve::setData to add my points.  Then I attached the plot to my curve and replotted the graph to see the curve.

I have to add a point every 500ms, is there a way to avoid replotting the whole thing every time I add a point?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [QCustomPlot](http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/). It's well documented and easy to implement.

If you go this route, the `addData()` function will do what you are asking.